# Statically compile pdftk for Heroku. Need to split PDF into single page files

Tags: ruby, pdf, heroku, split, pdftk

So we're using heroku to host our rails application. We've moved to the cedar stack. This stack does not have the pdftk library installed. I contacted support and was told to statically compile it for amd64 ubuntu and include it in my application.

This has proved more difficult than I thought. Initially I downloaded the package for ubuntu (http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/pdftk), extracted it, and included the binary file as well as the shared libraries. I'm getting strange errors like:

```
Unhandled Java Exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfCopy.copyIndirect(pdftk)
   at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfCopy.copyObject(pdftk)
   at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfCopy.copyDictionary(pdftk)
```

I'm assuming this is because some of the dependencies aren't installed?

### So here are my questions:

1. Is there an easier way to statically compile a library? Or do I need to move over its binary file as well as all of its libraries and dependencies?
2. I'm just trying to split a multi-page PDF into single page files in ruby. Is there a way to do this without PDFTK? Or am I stuck with trying to statically compile PDFTK?

Thanks for the help, I know this isn't an easy problem, but would really appreciate help with this one. I've wasted close to 6 hours trying to get this damn thing to work.

Comment: Have you tried building it using the Heroku vulcan build server? https://github.com/heroku/vulcan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Heroku keeps stripping out magic to add flexibility. As a result it feels more and more like the days when I used to manage and maintain my own servers. There is no easy solution. My "monkey patch" is to send the file to a server that I can install PDFTK, process the file, and send it back. Not great, but it works. Having to deal with this defeats the purpose of using heroku.

Answer (score 3):

The easy solution is to add the one dependency for pdftk that is not found on heroku.

```
$ldd pdftk
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff43ca000)
    libgcj.so.10 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1d26d48000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1d26ac4000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1d268ad000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1d2652a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1d2630c000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1d27064000)
```

I put pdftk and libgcj.so.10 into the /bin directory of my app. You then just need to tell heroku to look at the /bin dir when loading libs.

You can type

```
$heroku config
LD_LIBRARY_PATH:             /app/.heroku/vendor/lib
LIBRARY_PATH:                /app/.heroku/vendor/lib
```

To see what your current LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to and then add /app/bin (or whatever dir you chose to store libgcj.so.10) to it.

```
$heroku config:set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib:/app/bin
```

The down side is that my slug size went from 15.9MB to 27.5MB

Answer (score 2):

We've encountered the same problem, the solution we came up with was to use Stapler instead https://github.com/hellerbarde/stapler, it's a python utility and only requires an extra module to be installed (pyPdf) on Heroku.

I've been oriented to this blog entry: http://theprogrammingbutler.com/blog/archives/2011/07/28/running-pdftotext-on-heroku/

Here are the steps I followed to install pyPdf:

Accessing the heroku bash console

```
heroku run bash
```

Installing the latest version of pyPdf

```
cd tmp
curl http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/pyPdf-1.13.tar.gz -o pyPdf-1.13.tar.gz
tar zxvf pyPdf-1.13.tar.gz
python setup.py install --user
```

This puts all the necessary files under a .local file at the root of the app. I just downloaded it and added it to our git repo, as well as the stapler utility. Finally I updated my code to use stapler instead of pdftk, et voilà! Splitting PDFs from Heroku again.

Another way, probably cleaner, would be to encapsulate it in a gem ( http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2816783 )

Answer (score 1):

I read [a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545937/how-to-add-pdftk-to-heroku-cedar-app), and found [this approach by Ryan Daigle](http://www.higherorderheroku.com/articles/using-vulcan-to-build-binary-dependencies-on-heroku/) that worked for me as well: instead of building local binaries that are hard to match to Heroku's servers, use the remote environment to compile and build the required dependencies. This is accomplished using the [Vulcan gem](https://github.com/heroku/vulcan), which is provided by Heroku.

[**Ryan's article "Building Dependency Binaries for Heroku Applications"**](http://www.higherorderheroku.com/articles/using-vulcan-to-build-binary-dependencies-on-heroku/)

Another approach by Jon Magic (untested by me), is to download and compile the dependency directly through Heroku's `bash`, e.g. directly on the server: [**"Compiling Executables on Heroku"**](http://theprogrammingbutler.com/blog/archives/2011/07/28/running-pdftotext-on-heroku/).

On a side note, both approaches are going to result in binaries that are going to break if Heroku's underlying environment changes enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try [prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/).

Comment: I don't think prawn can split an existing PDF file and merge it back together. I think its more for PDF generation.

Comment: @Binary Logic Actually, I think prawn can.  Check out the `start_new_page` method.  You can pass in the path to another PDF to use as a "template" and even specify the page number to use.  Like so: `start_new_page(:template => filename, :template_page => 2)`