# Save desired pdf page from pdf file using ruby

Tags: ruby, pdf-generation

I have a pdf file. I want to save a given page (page #5, for intsance) as other pdf file. How do I accomplish this?

So far I've used `pdf-reader` gem – but it's suitable for reading pdfs (though I can get to the page I want), and I gem `prawn` – this one's only for writing pdf (I can only create empty pdf file).

Answer (score 3):

It was here: [Statically compile pdftk for Heroku. Need to split PDF into single page files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128855/statically-compile-pdftk-for-heroku-need-to-split-pdf-into-single-page-files)

Try something like:

```
require 'prawn'

Prawn::Document.generate('new.pdf') do |pdf|
  pdf.start_new_page(:template => "input.pdf", :template_page => 5)
end
```

Comment: Yes, it's work, but method start_new_page create blank page before expected page. Do you know, why?

Comment: @GavrilovPavel Add `:skip_page_creation => true` to the generate method call

Comment: No, sorry. Try to hack method start_new_page in document.rb of Prawn gem.

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev This works: `Prawn::Document.generate('new.pdf', :skip_page_creation => true){|pdf| pdf.start_new_page(:template => "input.pdf", :template_page => 5) }`

Comment: this solution gives empty pdf, is it intended behavior or m I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know on what system you are, but on my ubuntu12.04 box, the pdftk program worked:

```
pdftk A=your_beautiful.pdf cat A3 output page3.pdf
```

So you could use backticks for this, and read up on http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-extract-pages-pdf